# To open Vim in ":" mode and die after enter

Tags: vim

Command

```
vim +"%s/fafa//gn" /tmp/1
```

which shows the count correctly but opens Vim (not wanted). 
I want to use Vim only for computation, although I know it is inefficient.

Pseudocommand

```
vim +"%s/fafa//gn" +"q" /tmp/1
```

but it does not show the count, only dies. 
I think there should be some sort of conditional operator, for instance AND.

How can you show count in ":" mode and die after user pressing enter?

Comment: Could you just not use `grep "fafa" /tmp/1 | wc -l`?

Comment: @Xophmeister Yes, I can but I am studying in this question some features of Vim.

Comment: Just to complement that grep command: `grep -n "fafa" /tmp/1` should be enough.

Comment: @Vitor What is the full command?

Comment: That is not a vim command, I was just expanding the solution given by @Xophmeister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine commands in command mode with pipes, which is similar to how you are doing it with multiple command line arguments. As such, try this:

```
vim +"%s/fafa//gne|exec getchar()|q" /tmp/1
```

Without the bit in the middle, it does exactly the same as your original example. However, the `exec getchar()` command is a bit of VimScript that -- how used here -- simply waits for keyboard input, so it doesn't exit immediately.